# Program asks for too many numbers when trying to add 2 arrays element wise

Tags: c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,sum = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int num1[n],num2[n],num3[n];
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&num1[i]);
        for(int j = 0 ;j<n;j++){
            scanf("%d",&num2[j]);
            for(int k = 0;k<n;k++){
                num3[k] = num1[i] + num2[j];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
        printf("%d ",num3[l]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to add the same indexed numbers from two arrays into a third array for a given size n. But it keeps asking for more numbers. Where is the problem?

Comment: Don't use nested for-loops. Use 3 individual for-loops.

Comment: any specific reason?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/qT7MzH

Comment: you are iterating n-times `scanf("%d",&num1[i]);` and n*n times `scanf("%d",&num2[j])`

Comment: @TanvirAnjum You ask: "any specific reason?" Well, because it's wrong... with nested loops you execute things over and over again... and you don't want that. You want to read into num1 **once**, read into num2 **once**, calculate num3 **once**. That is done with 3 individual for-loops

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use nested loops?

Comment: What input do you want [after getting `n`]? Do you want (1) _disjoint:_ read all `num1` and then read all `num2` or (2) _pairs:_ Read num1[0], read num2[0], read num1[1], read num2[1], ..., read num1[n - 1], read num2[n - 1]?

Answer (score 0):

You want to take 2 array as input and store their sum to a third array, i.e. `sum[i] = num1[i]+num2[i]`. Now, the array `num1` and `num2` are in no way dependent on one another. But the array `sum` is dependent on both `num1` and `num2`.
So, You will take input `num1` and `num2` as independent arrays, and then use another loop to add the two arrays.

```
loop i from 0 to n: take num1[i]
loop i from 0 to n: take num2[i]
loop i from 0 to n: sum[i]=num1[i]+num2[i]
print sum[i];
```